Spring Cloud Gateway Discovered Routes based on actual URL Path rather than service id
I want to use service discovery to route based on url ignoring the service id.
Following is I am trying to achieve following.

These are discovered routes
Route{id='ReactiveCompositeDiscoveryClient_ADDRESS-SERVICE', uri=lb://ADDRESS-SERVICE, order=0, predicate=Paths: [/address-service/**], match trailing slash: true, gatewayFilters=[[[RewritePath //?(?<remaining>.*) = '/${remaining}'], order = 1]]}
Route{id='ReactiveCompositeDiscoveryClient_NAME-SERVICE', uri=lb://NAME-SERVICE, order=0, predicate=Paths: [/name-service/**], match trailing slash: true, gatewayFilters=[[[RewritePath //?(?<remaining>.*) = '/${remaining}'], order = 1]]}
Route{id='ReactiveCompositeDiscoveryClient_ACCOUNT-SERVICE', uri=lb://ACCOUNT-SERVICE, order=0, predicate=Paths: [/account-service/**], match trailing slash: true, gatewayFilters=[[[RewritePath //?(?<remaining>.*) = '/${remaining}'], order = 1]]}

The route discovery is working if I use below urls
http://gateway/account-service/service/ReqAccount
http://gateway/name-service/service/ReqName
http://gateway/address-service/service/ReqAddress

I want to use the api without service name like below
http://gateway/service/ReqAccount
http://gateway/service/ReqName
http://gateway/service/ReqAddress

